# Facebook auth popup not closing when using HTTPS

Tags: facebook, authentication, https

I have a Facebook app which points to a Flash application, and where I'm using Facebook login.
When I access Facebook app via HTTP, I see the auth popup opening/disappearing and I'm authenticated.
However, if I access Facebook app via HTTPS, Facebook auth popup opens, I'm authenticated, but popup won't close by itself.
Can this be some sort of Facebook bug, when using HTTPS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yep.  It's a bug.  Look for it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) and you'll be able to track its status.

Comment: Which of that list are you referring? Can't see any indication that its related to HTTPS only

Comment: That is a list of all the bugs on facebook... I can't find that specific one right now... but I saw a bug dealing with the login popup being blank and not closing... If I come across it again I'll post it...

Comment: Maybe this one: [Fb Login button does not trigger back, and keep hanging after successful login](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/421137377931628)?